# How to add a domain to existing certificate generated by Let’s Encrypt/Certbot?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, letsencrypt, certbot

This question is a continuation of essentially [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302401/letsencrypt-add-domain-to-existing-certificate) that was closed for being "off-topic" on Stack Overflow.
The OP's question:

> I am just simply trying to add the domain `test.example.com` to the certificate that already exists for `example.com`. How do I add a domain to my existing certificate and replace the old certificate?

Answer (score 27):

With certbot 0.34.0, the procedure is simple and easy (depending on your system, substitute `certbot-auto` or `~/certbot-auto` for `certbot`):

First, list your existing certificate and domains:

```
sudo certbot certificates
```

This will return your certificate name and the domains currently on the certificate, for example:

> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
>   Found the following certs:   Certificate Name: foo.example.com
>       Domains: foo.example.com bar.example.com
>       Expiry Date: 2119-08-01 11:30:32+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
>       Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.example.com/fullchain.pem
>       Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.example.com/privkey.pem
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

Then add commas between the domains listed after the Domains: line above, add another comma, and the domain you want to add, for example, to add baz.example.com:

```
sudo certbot --expand -d foo.example.com,bar.example.com,baz.example.com
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you!